# Ask something to be something

Tags: sentence-meaning

Below is an extract from a news article and I am confused where with texts in **bold**.
My interpretation is that the lawyers have asked someone (perhaps from the authority) to have Djokovic transferred to a place nicer than where he is currently kept. But I cannot understand why it says 'asked he be moved' instead of 'asked him be moved'?

> While he awaits a final decision, Djokovic's lawyers have **asked he
> be moved** from the immigration detention hotel that has often been
> criticised by refugees for its poor conditions where he is currently
> being held, to "a more suitable place of detention" that would allow
> him to train ahead of the Australian Open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a subjunctive.  And they are rather rare and formal in modern English.

The standard way to express this is to write "asked for him to be moved".

Alternatively you can use a subordinator "that":  "asked that he be moved".

However an alternative is to use a clause with a subjunctive verb and no subordinator. Here it is also passive.  The clause with the subjunctive verb has a subject which is in the usual subject form (unlike the implied subject in the infinitive clause above)

So you can say

> I asked she write to her mother.

It is a formal and *rare* form of

> I asked for her to write to her mother.

Similarly

> I asked he be moved to a more suitable place.

is the same meaning as

> I asked for him to be moved to a more suitable place.